# getIntent error, doesnt get recognized

Tags: android

getIntent does not get recognized, what I am doing wrong?

I get this error:

> error: cannot find symbol variable getIntent

PS: at first I got this error cannot find symbol method getIntent.

My code:

```
package com.example.r.app;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    int i=0;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

        Intent intent = getIntent;
        int[] barva = intent.getIntArrayExtra("barva");

        int[] bar = {1, 2, 3};

        if (position == i) {
            if (barva == bar){
                textView.setTextColor(0xffcc80);
            }
            else if (barva == bar){
                textView.setTextColor(0xa5d6a7);
            }
            else if (barva == bar){
                textView.setTextColor(0x80deea);
            }

        }
         return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> error: cannot find symbol variable getIntent

First,`getIntent` is method instead of variable so call it as:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

Second, `getIntent()` method is from `Activity` class instead of `ArrayAdapter` class so this method is not available in class which is extending `ArrayAdapter`.

Call `getIntent()` method from Activity in which creating object of  `MyAdapter` and pass intent as parameter to constructor.

Comment: Ok, I've did it, but now I get this error: non-static method getIntent() cannot be referenced from static context. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You mean this? Intent intent = Results.getIntent(); int[] barva = intent.getIntArrayExtra("barva");

Comment: This is where I call it from, but it is not in onCreate..:

Intent intent3 = new Intent(Game.this, MyAdapter.class);
int [] barva2 = Arrays.copyOf(barva, g);
intent3.putExtra("barva", barva2);
startActivityForResult(intent3, 1);

Comment: How could then I pass array int to MyAdapter?

Comment: @Everlastinf: show code where adding `MyAdapter` adapter to ListView

Comment: `Intent intent = getIntent();
        String[] rez = intent.getStringArrayExtra("key");

        List<String> rez3 = Arrays.asList(rez);

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getListView().getContext(), R.layout.row, rez3);
        getListView().setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: @Everlastinf: fixed or not?

Comment: It did, but it doesn't seem to pass any value.

Comment: I think something is wrong with if statements.. because all text in textView is transperant..http://i57.tinypic.com/qx85xe.png if you are willing to check this out.

Comment: It is the same.. trasperant text.

Comment: I did and still no text. http://i61.tinypic.com/2rh0i1t.png here is code of activity where listView is called.

Comment: @Everlastinf : see following tutorial and change getView method probably help http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter

Comment: It was something wrong with setTextColor.. now it works, because I have used different code (example: textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#a5d6a7"));) Thank for everything!

Answer (score 4):

getIntent is a method. Inside an activity try:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

Edit:

I didnt really noticed you're inside an Adapter. If your context relates to the activity, you have to do it slightly different:

```
Intent intent = ((Activity) context).getIntent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can write in your class declaration:

public class nameofyourclass extends AppCompatActivity {